# separate vs separate out

Tags: word-choice

I cannot bear to hear separate out, but maybe it's just me. Is this correct? When I do the laundry, I need to separate out the red shirts so that my underwear doesn't turn pink.

Comment: what if the sentence was this: When I do the laundry, I need to separate out the red shirts from the white laundry so that my underwear doesn't turn red.  Is this correct? ps I hate it, lol.

Comment: of possible interest - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_phrasal_verbs_with_particle_(out)

Answer (score 6):

'Separate out' is used when you are talking about one or more items that have to be removed from the general population.

'Please separate out the green and the blue ribbons from all the others'

The verb 'separate' is used when you are mentioning two categories of things by name that are to be divided.

'On the day of judgement the sheep will be separated from the goats'. (NB This is for illustration purposes only. I am not a theologian.)

Comment: thanks for your replies. ws2, can you direct me to a citation for your information? thanks, molly

Comment: I agree with you about the distinction, and the usefulness of both terms. On a point of detail, you hyphenated it at first, but then you didn't in the example. I reckon it shouldn't be hyphenated, since the two words are functionally separate. "Separate out the x from all the y" is just another way of saying "Separate the X out from all the Y".

Comment: @EditingFrank Yes I believe you are right about the hyphen, so I have removed it. Thank you.

Comment: I think it is stronger than just *mentioning*. When one uses *separate out*, one *creates* ad hoc categories. If you separate a couple kids who were fighting, there isn't any categorization. And focus tends to follow the separated-out things. If I didn't want pink skivvies, I would separate out the *whites* and do a load. I wouldn't say "separate out the red shop rags" and then try to return focus to the remaining laundry.

Answer (score -2):

To separate means to divide out. To add "out" after the word separate is unnecessary and slovenly, creating the nonsensical to "divide out out"